# MDX- I need to sum each month's amount with the next month's amount only, not a running total

Tags: mdx

I have output from a MDX query that looks like this:

Duration             Month    A   B

1     13-Jan            $ 436940       $2377

1   13-Feb  420652  1590

1   13-Mar  412365  2265

2   13-Jan  432589  2374

2   13-Feb  362598  1136

2   13-Mar  263598  3965

etc, for 5 Durations, 12 months each duration. 
A and B are derived from Members
I need to be able to have a C column that is the sum of A for Duration 1 Jan 13 & Duration 1 Feb 13. Then the sum of A for Duration 1 Feb 13 and Duration 1 March 13, and so on. I do not know how to do this in MDX and could only find posts addressing how to do a running total, or total a row instead of a column, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Member [Date].[2 Months Sales] as

(
([Date].[Calendar].[Month].currentMember ,[sales].[sales]) + ([Date].[Calendar].[Month].NextMember ,[sales].[sales])
)

select [Sales].[sales] on rows,

[Date].[2 Months Sales] on Columns from [Cube]